# How to view the content UITableView's reusable pool

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I was trying to deep dive into how the `UITableView` works internally. I've already read multiple posts regarding that like,

https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-02-22-lets-build-uitableview.html

I want to know if there is any way we can look into the content of the **reusable pool**, i.e. how many and what all `UITableViewCell` types are available inside it at a moment.

I already know that we'll have the `cells` as per the *screen size* and the *`cell` height*. But I'm trying to figure out what happens if the `tableView` accepts different types of `cells` at different `indexPaths`.

Comment: It’s unlikely cells ever get destroyed, and they are most likely created on demand, so if you keep weak references to them as they are created and know which are in use at any moment, you can get a full picture of all cells.

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking: If I have `CellTypeA` at `[0,0]` and then 50 rows of `CellTypeB`, and I scroll down to row 40... is there a `CellTypeA` *"sitting in a reuse pool"*? However... ***why*** do you want to know that?

Comment: @DonMag like I specified in the question, I just want a better understanding of how tableView actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you *can* dig down into the objects in debug...

I set a breakpoint in `didSelectRowAt` and looked into the Variables View pane:

[image]

I had one row (index path `[0,3]` that used `TestCellB` and 90 rows that used `TestCell`, and the table was scrolled to row 21 (so row `[0,3]` was well off-screen.

As you can see, there is an internal `Dictionary` named `_reusableTableCells` which, in my example, currently contains ***1*** `TestCellB` and ***2*** `TestCell`s.

---

**EDIT**

I just gave this a try - might give you some additional info:

```
    var reusableCells = tableView.value(forKey: "_reusableTableCells")
    print(reusableCells)
```

Output:

```
Optional({
    TestCellB =     (
        "<TranslateTest.TestCellB: 0x7f87b206aa00; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 1612; 414 37); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x600003a66380>>"
    );
    TestCellC =     (
        "<TranslateTest.TestCellC: 0x7f87b2894800; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 205; 414 93); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x600003a586e0>>",
        "<TranslateTest.TestCellC: 0x7f87b3000e00; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 298; 414 93); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x600003a5fe40>>"
    );
})
```

Comment: So, the `_reuableTableCells` are those that aren't currently visible on the screen right?

Comment: @PGDev - Yep, that's what quick testing indicates.

Comment: @PGDev - take a look at my edit (easier than breaking into debug to inspect).

Comment: One question though. If there are like 100 cells of type TestCell. I scrolled down to 99th cell. Now there are 8 cells  visible on the screen. And in the _reuableTableCells, there are another 8-9 cells available. So, what will be the possible size of the pool? And why are 8-9 cells still available in the pool? Should there be 1/2 that just went off screen?

Comment: I imagine internally there is some optimization algorithm(s) going on. After more quick testing, I see the number of `_reusableTableCells` changing as I scroll up and down, dropping back to Zero at certain points.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the answer 