In current UIKit is there a way to access the array of all current cells in the recycler pool?
I've just looked at the headers of UITableView and can't see anything; in olden days there was an array something like "_reusableCells" but it seems to be gone.
I guess one could keep a list of them as they are made but (a) not performant (b) a bit messy/impossible to watch them be released etc.
Is there a way?
I suppose having them all sign up for a notification is one approach, but it seems a bit fraught.

Found it! (The old version.)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6164346/294884
This seems to no longer exists in UIKit - does anyone know how to find it today?

What problem are you actually trying to solve? Why do you need to access these queued cells? It would be helpful to update your question with more specifics about your goals.

They where marked with @private and you wasn't able to use them, isn't it?

@HangarRash how are you.   ?  The question seems pretty clear?   I'm not sure why the use-case at hand is relevant?  You can easily think of numerous reasons, or for that matter you may just want to know for knowledge' sake, perhaps for debugging etc.

@Cy-4AH - it's not that it is marked with private, but, I simply can't find it!  Back in the obj-c days, you could see and use it clearly.  I forget the exact name, but it was like "_reusableTableViewCells" array.  Actually there are a couple of ancient questions on here  regarding the issue which mention it (I can't find one just now).  There are any number of questions on here about the obvious need to (say) purge the current recycler cells (say, when dealing with layout changes when skimming) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286669/how-to-purge-a-cached-uitableviewcell

@Cy-4AH found it!  notice edit to question and linked https://stackoverflow.com/a/6164346/294884

If you intent to use private API with valueForKey, then you can retrieve hidden properties and methods from Objective-C runtime, for example with class_copyPropertyList and class_copyMethodList. I think I have seen somewhere on Github repository with private headers.

@Cy-4AH ahhhh!  I get you, I did not realize it was at the "objective C level".   I have no idea how to access such structures so I will look in to it, good one!

a little (old) discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57481395/6257435

WTT @DonMag it seems to be this simple,
let spares = mainTable.value(forKey: "_reusableTableCells")
print(spares, "\n\n")

It seems this gives the list of reusable cells not currently in use, ie literally the "offscreen" ones, rather than giving you "all assembled cells, in use or on standby".
Thus if you need to (say) flag "all cells" in some way, you'd add together that set and all showing ones.

This may be fine as an "intellectual exercise" but... I would never do anything with it in a production environment. No way of knowing if touching those cells would be thread-safe... no way of knowing what UIKit might do with them... etc. Tableviews and cells have been around a long time, and memory management has been highly optimized. Can't imagine ever needing (or wanting) to do something like "purge" them.

? it's commonplace / ubiquitous that you dynamically change the layout of all the cells??  (An every day example is a "columns" like situation.)  As sioon as you get in to performance and skimming issues, you can't just redo everything willynilly. You may have misunderstood my use of "purge", I changed it to "flag".  ie purging on the level of your own custom data in the cells (constraints or something might be a good example). We often just use a series number of the table and the cells look at it to see if they need to change (their layout .. or whatever the concept is). tremendously cleane

r would be just setting a flag "do whatever it is from scratch".  So!  Again sorry if "purge" was confusing, my bad .. I just meant flag them all for whatever reason (ie purge "my" data, layout or whatever).

Maybe you have an actual use case, but I can't think of anything that couldn't be don't in the cell's prepareForReuse or in the controller's cellForRowAtIndexPath or willDisplayCell ... that would merit the risks of messing with "_reusableTableCells"

a common & obvious example is doing "columns", as mentioned.  you have to write extremely performant cells, and all you can afford to do is change is the text in all the labels; but when the actual let's call it template changes, it's a basic that you have to flag all cells in the overall pool that the next time they get data (and only then), they have to change to the new template. as I say you just do this with a global series number or such, so they all know. but i can't see the slightest problem with flipping a flag in all of them using this _reusableTableCells key?

anyways its like 3 lines of code, I'll try it and report and paste the results!!!
